# I get this error when installing a gem: "ERROR: While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gzip, zlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ERROR: While executing gem … (Zlib::GzipFile::Error) not in gzip format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684137/error-while-executing-gem-zlibgzipfileerror-not-in-gzip-format)

When installing a gem on my system, I get the following error:

```
gem install blackbook --version ">= 1.0.7" --source http://github.com/tamoyal/blackbook/tree/master
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?  I built the gem so maybe it is something wrong with my gem build?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something isn't set up properly to fetch the gem from GitHub.

try `gem fetch -V`

```
steve@macpro:~$ gem fetch blackbook --version ">= 1.0.7" --source http://github.com/tamoyal/blackbook/tree/master -V
GET 301 Moved Permanently: http://github.com/tamoyal/blackbook/tree/master/specs.4.8.gz
GET 200 OK: http://github.com/tamoyal/blackbook/tree/master/
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format
```

You're getting the "not in gzip format" error because `gem` can't fetch `specs.4.8.gz`. GitHub returns a 301 redirect back to your project home page, which of course isn't what it wants and isn't gzipped.

Sorry I can't help you further, but I haven't build a gem, much less on GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly your gem sources are not set up correctly.  http://gems.rubyforge.org/ used to be a correct path to rubygems, but it no longer exists.

run this command:

```
gem sources
```

If you see http://gems.rubyforge.org/ in your list run:

```
gem sources -r http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

You may also need to add in rubygems.org as a valid source

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mentioned your system. However it happens on Ubuntu if you do not have zlib library. The solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libzlib-ruby
```

P.S. I know the question is more than 2 years old. I just hope it might help someone else.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for posting... just had this issue even 16 months after you posted.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error was coming to me also.
Finally I found that the Proxy settings was not correct.
Please check that you can reach the gem server from command line.
Just ping it :)