# ERROR: While executing gem with local gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I came across
[**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13684137/error-while-executing-gem)
and the answer suggests to manually download the gems instead of having them pulled by `gem install`.

Well I am received the same error despite using a local gem file.

```
$ git clone git://github.com/mojombo/jekyll.git

$ cd jekyll

$ gem build jekyll.gemspec
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: jekyll
  Version: 0.12.0
  File: jekyll-0.12.0.gem

$ gem install jekyll-0.12.0.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing my DNS as detailed in this question

[Rubygems blocked by Norton DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951135/rubygems-blocked-by-norton-dns)

I ran [namebench](http://code.google.com/p/namebench) and have switched to OpenDNS-2.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build and install the gem successfully just now, perhaps this might help you: [I get this error when installing a gem: "ERROR: While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937608/i-get-this-error-when-installing-a-gem-error-while-executing-gem-zlibg)

Regards,