# Rubygems blocked by Norton DNS

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I ran

```
$ gem fetch -V github-linguist
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format
```

then to my shock I opened the link in my browser and see
[this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX5rc.png)

```
Norton DNS
Malicious Web Site Blocked
You attempted to access: production.s3.rubygems.org
This is a known malicious web site. It is recommended that you do NOT visit 
this site. This site points to production.s3.rubygems.org.s3.amazonaws.com, 
which is malicious.
```

On [pencil’s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14951325) I ran
[namebench](http://code.google.com/p/namebench) and have switched to OpenDNS-2.

Comment: Rubygems has nothing to do with Norton, so I'd go with the ISP being the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably someone used AWS to distribute malware and some buggy automatism now blockes *.amazonaws.com

Must be a filter anywhere between you and Amazon (Router/Firewall, Proxy, ISP, Name Server, ...). Start by using different name servers (like Google's 8.8.8.8).