# Unable to install any Gems (watir-webdriver, selenium-webdriver)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir, watir-webdriver

I install the Ruby:  Successful

```
ruby -v
=> ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]

gem -v
=> 1.8.24

gem source
=> *** CURRENT SOURCES ***
=> http://rubygems.org/
```

When I try to install any gem:  Failed.

Worked good for me from home, but it's not working from my work place.  I tried pinging the rubygems.org site, but it's not pinging.  I downloaded the gems straight from the site and put it in the folder: (watir-webdriver)
`C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>`

Installed gems like this: `C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem install watir-webdriver`

Getting this error: `C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems>gem install watir-webdriver
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format`

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Are you behind a proxy? In that case see this pages for help:

- http://watir.com/installation/
- http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIgeminstallWatirbehindaproxyserver%3F

Comment: If you're all good now, then please accept @Željko's answer.  It'll help keep SO tidy.

Comment: Or Daves answer, whichever one helped you the most.. The key is that by accepting an answer, it also indicates the question has been answered and does not show up as open/unresolved.   It also gives credit to the folks who take time to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing on linux (which I had a similar issue on Ubuntu), you will need to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937608/i-get-this-error-when-installing-a-gem-error-while-executing-gem-zlibg)

First, get the right zlib driver

```
sudo apt-get install libzlib-ruby
```

Second, check your sources and possibly add to them:

```
gem sources
gem sources -a http://gems.rubyforge.org/
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
```

BTW, I had a long process of updating my various libraries on Ubuntu to enable reasonable IRB interaction (history, tab-complete, color, etc.) on Ubuntu. It took some work but was worth it to be able to use RVM.

Comment: I did this and everything working fine now: "SET HOME = %USERPROFILE%"