# Why does installing the Rails gem on Ubuntu raise a Zlib::GzipFile::Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

Here is what I'm doing

```
sudo gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    unexpected end of file
alex@ubuntu:~/Documents/$ sudo gem fetch -V rails
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    unexpected end of file
```

I googled on this but didn't find anything valuable. I even installed

```
sudo apt-get install libzlib-ruby
```

and I was able to install rake this way

```
gem install rake
```

The odd thing is that if I say just `gem install rails` then nothing happens at all.

```
gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://rubygems.org/
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I had trouble installing Rails, but it's because my dev environment wasn't properly configured before trying to install it. Not sure if it helps, but here's a blog post that I used to install RVM and Rails without difficulty:  http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: Your're not behind any sort of proxy?

Comment: Also, try reviewing, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4168690/2195308

Comment: Are you sure your Ruby installation is alright? Did you run `gem update --system`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't Do That

Installing system gems on Debian-based systems is a bad idea. Don't do that. Either use the system packages, or use a Ruby environment-management tool like [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/).

### Using System Packages

Depending on your version of Ubuntu, use:

```
# Rails 2.3 on Ubuntu 12.10
sudo apt-get install rails

# Rails 3.2 on Ubuntu 12.10
sudo apt-get install rails3
```

or find available Rails metapackages for your version with `apt-cache search`.

### Install rbenv On Ubuntu 12.10

If you're using Ubuntu 12.10, you can install rbenv and ruby-build as system packages, too. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-suggests rbenv ruby-build
```

Comment: 'Installing system gems on Debian-based systems is a bad idea. ' why?

Comment: @ted Among other reasons, because it often breaks system packages and dependencies. YMMV.